# Why is the Venn Diagram Considered a Special Case of the Formula for Unions

Tags: probability, statistics

$P( A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$

Or in Boolean terms: $P(A + B|C) = P(A|C) + P(B|C) - P(AB|C)$

I've read a lot of information but still can't piece together why this would be considered a "special case." The explanation goes into questioning what the points on the Venn Diagram really mean and dissolving $A$ and $B$ into infinitely smaller subsets without overlap. At least, this is what I took of it.

But even if $A$ is made up of countless subsets, is it not still intuitive that the union of $A$ and $B$ is the area of both $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ minus the overlap of $P(A \cap B)$?

I'd be happy if someone could shed some light on this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm really not sure what it means to be a "special case." It is not a case, but a motivating tool, and in measure theory, it serves as a guiding principle but nothing more. The reason being that Borel sets might have that nice graphical representation but any arbitrary element in the $\sigma$-algebra could be totally bizarre and not admit such a nice graphical representation. (So maybe in this sense it is a "special case" but that feels like really weird posturing to me.)

Comment: Conditioning to C was just how I saw it presented in the Boolean Algebra sense. But the authors of the text I was reading were presenting the text in a way I had trouble understanding. They claimed that in stating that, for example, A = It will rain, then in the Venn Diagram, when dissolved into individual points, we would have to understand what the points mean. In the case of rain they would represent each individual rain drop's trajectory, for example, which doesn't serve useful. I the general sense I don't think it's super important, though I find the argument interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not about the area. Take $A$ as the set of all multiples of 3 and take $B$ as the set of all multiples of 5.Now if you choose a number. Then $P(A\cup B)$ you will have probability of $A$ + probability of $B$ but doing this counts the probability of $A+B$ twice and so we have to subtract that.

Finally you will have $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$

Venn diagram is not any **special case** it is just diagram representation of sets and operations over sets.

Comment: In my text 'Probability Theory: The logic of science' there is about a page devoted to explaining why derivation of this is important and that we can't use the Venn Diagram to justify this equation.

Comment: You can verify an equation with Venn diagram but it cannot be used to prove any equation because it is just a representation not a proving technique.

Comment: http://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/prob/book.pdf

Might give you a better idea of what I'm trying to say. It's on page 42 after Godel's Theorem. I have the full book but this is an incomplete online version. Perhaps their wording is confusing me.

Comment: See (2-105) & (2-106) book is saying that Venn diagram is not suitable for those kind of cases. But Venn diagram is suitable for a case as in my answer. See a paragraph just above (2-105). There is a line "In the  special  case  where  those  propositions  happen  to  be  statements  about  sets". These are the cases were Venn diagram is not suitable. What will be the cardinality of A as defined in (2-105). You cannot answer. Is this clear now?

Comment: Yes you pointed me to the correct part of that section. I considered this explanation promptly but then resumed my reading without thinking of it much. But now I recall them mentioning how it would be unreasonable to consider every individual rain drop and their trajectories in a rainstorm. I see how we make up A and B now. Thank you!